# Disable wrap in base class TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have installed plugin news. It is generating such html:

```html
<div id="c69" class="csc-default">
  <div class="news">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want remove this wrapping. I don't have it in my templates. They are generated automatic. How can I do it? Typo3 version 7.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable using TypoScript

> tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >

Put above line in your Template > root template > Setup 
It'll give you clean HTML output as your layout without default wrap of css_styled_content. or if you see classes with extension related then must be from extension which you used. In extBase structure you'll find ext_key/Resources/Private/Layouts and Templates.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="c69" class="csc-default">
```

comes form the ext. `css_styled_content`. You can rewrite this so you don't have this wrapping. Could be done global or per page.

if you use tt_news, the wrapping for the ext. comes from the `wrapInBaseClass()`

if you use tx_news, you will find the wrapping in the templates of the extension, probably in the Layout template